# FFT: Does the result of $N \log_2(N)$ stand for total operations or (complex) adds and multiplies?

Tags: fft

Calculate the amount of operations you need for the Fast Fourier Transform.

Take $N=2048 \times 2048$

$N\dfrac{\log(N)}{\log(2)}$

$\dfrac{\log(2048 \times 2048)}{\log(2)}$ is 22.

$(2048 \times 2048) \dfrac{\log(2048 \times 2048)}{\log(2)}$ is 92274688.

But does $92274688$ stand for total operations or $92274688$ adds AND $92274688$ multiiplications?

So the total amount of operations is $2\times 92274688=184549376$.

Comment: I suppose to get a 2D FFT. width is 1920 and height is 1080. Why can't I use this for a 2D FFT? I remember that not all FFTs require a N with a power of 2. Are you sure I'm wrong?

Comment: Deleted my comments. I'm going to submit an answer with some clarification.

Comment: This integer sequence in the oeis might be relevant: http://oeis.org/A059975
"n*a(n) is the number of complex multiplications needed for the fast Fourier transform of n numbers"

Comment: I read that FFTW supports combinations of powers of small primes (2, 3, 5, 7). 1080 = $1920 = 2^7 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ $2^3 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5$. I read that FFTW should be able to process these without any padding for 1920*1080.

Comment: Indeed it can, but of course the cost isn't an easy formula based on $\log_2$ anymore.

Answer (score 4):

{EDIT: The original question concerned a $1920\times 1080$ FFT, not a $2040\times 2048$ FFT. So the parts of this answer that deal with sizes that are not powers of two are no longer relevant. I will leave them anyway. The last part of this answer, dealing with complex vs. real operations, remains relevant.}

A 2-D FFT of size $N_1\times N_2$ is equivalent to performing $N_1$ FFTs of size $N_2$, and $N_2$ FFTs of size $N_1$. So the cost becomes 
$$C_{2D}(N_1,N_2) = N_1C_{1D}(N_2)+N_2C_{1D}(N_1),$$ where $C_{1D}(N)$ is the cost of a single $N$-point, 1-D FFT. Your proposed calculations are correct, then, *if* you assume $C_{1D}(N)=2N\log_2 N$, because this evaluates to $$2N_1N_2(\log_2 N_1+\log_2 N_2)=2N_1N_2\log_2(N_1N_2).$$

*[EDIT: This paragraph is no longer relevant; the OP has changed the FFT sizes to a power of two.]* However, your other problem is that $C(N)$ is *not* necessarily $kN\log_2 N$ (or close to it) unless $N$ is a power of two. In particular, if $N$ is prime, then you're going to need $kN^2$ operations. For values of $N$ that are composite prime factors, then the computational complexity is a function of the number of prime factors and their values. See [this page](http://cnx.org/content/m16335/latest/) for a discussion of efficient prime factor FFTs. *Roughly* speaking, if the number of prime factors is sufficiently large, then the cost is going to grow like $N\log N$.

Even for powers of two, $C_{1D}(N)=2N\log_2 N$ is not quite right for several reasons. First of all, the standard radix-2 FFT actually requires $(N/2)\log_2 N$ complex multiplications and $N\log_2 N$ complex additions. Furthermore, you really don't want to just add these two counts together. After all, one complex addition requires 2 real additions, and one complex multiplication requires 4 multiplications and 2 additions. So if you want to combine these two operation counts, you need to do it in terms of these *real* operations, giving you $C_{1D}=5N\log_2 N$ *real* operations.

You can do significantly better than this, it turns out, if you take a careful accounting of "trivial" complex multiplications. One of the most efficient algorithms from a real operation standpoint is the *split-radix* algorithm (which requires a power of two) requires $C_{1D}(N)=4N\log_2 N-6N+8$ real multiplications and additions for a single FFT. For a 2-D FFT of size $N_1\times N_2$, the total cost would be 
$$\begin{aligned}
C_{2D}(N_1,N_2)&=N_1(4N_2\log_2 N_2-6N_2+8)+N_2(4N_1\log_2 N_1-6N_1+8)\\
&=4N_1N_2\log_2(N_1N_2)-12N_1N_2+8(N_1+N_2).
\end{aligned}$$

Finally, let me add that counting floating point operations is a crude way to measure practical performance. Memory access patterns are often a more important factor in performance. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform): "In practice, actual performance on modern computers is usually dominated by factors other than the speed of arithmetic operations and the analysis is a complicated subject (see, e.g., Frigo & Johnson, 2005), but the overall improvement from O(N2) to O(N log N) remains."

Comment: 'M rows x N cols, and a 2D FFT requires 1D FFTs on all rows followed by 1D column-wise FFTs on the result.
MNlogN+NMlogM=MN(logM+logN)=MNlogMN'. I can't the MN by N=2048?

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking. Can you rephrase?

Comment: See updated question. Is that correct?

Comment: I still don't get it. "I can't the MN by N=2048?" What does that mean?

Comment: Paul R said that the complexity of a 2D FFT was: MNlogMN. M stands for amount of rows. N stands for amount of columns.

Comment: Oh I see, you have updated the question to 2048 x 2048. Then yes, some of my answer no longer applies---the parts that refer to non-powers of two. But the rest does.

Comment: To be clear: You don't agree that the complexity is MNlogMN=2048*2048log(2048*2048)

Comment: I do not agree. I agree that it is $O(MN\log MN)$ however. In other words, it's correct to within a multiplicative constant, *if* you ignore lower-order terms.

Comment: Didn't you wrote in your large answer that it isn't MNlogMN, but 2*MNlogMN?

Comment: No. See the text: "Even for powers of two..." and onwards.

Comment: "$\begin{aligned}
\\
&4N_1N_2\log_2(N_1N_2)-12N_1N_2+8(N_1+N_2).
\end{aligned}$"                                                             Does that mean that I need more than 92274688 adds AND more than 92274688 multiplications? (see question)

Comment: 4*2048*2048*log(2048*2048)/log(2)-12*2048*2048+8(2048+2048)=318.799.872 operations?

Comment: Does '318.799.872 operations' (see comment above) include the operations needed for the Inverse Fourier Transform?

Comment: I read that FFTW supports combinations of powers of small primes (2, 3, 5, 7). $1920 = 2^7 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ $1080 =  2^3 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5$. I read that FFTW should be able to process these without any padding for 1920*1080.

Comment: MJD wrote that Gauss discovered that if you are willing to do 5 additions instead of 2, you can reduce the multiplications from 4 to 3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Gauss.27s_complex_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: Right. But with modern processors that is not likely to be a win, especially if there are fused multiply-adds. And it comes at a cost of reduced precision.

Comment: Oh for goodness' sake. I'm done here.

Comment: Yes. You really are being ridiculous now. Please go read a basic computational mathematics text.

Comment: Wait, 2 real additions + 4 multiplications and 2 additions... Aren't those 2+4+2=8 operations?

Comment: Yes, but you only need half as many complex multiplcations, so it's 2+2+1=5 operations. I have corrected it.

Comment: Textbook says 'Multiplication involves four individual multiplications ac,ad,bc,bd, one substraction (ac-bd, and one addition ad+bc: (a +jb) x (c+jd) = ac+ j(ad+bc)+ $J^2bd$) = (ac-bd)+j(ad+bc).' You were talking about 2 additions.

Comment: Please read a text on how floating-point arithmetic is performed. ANY TEXT. Then you will understand that the *same circuit* performs addition and subtraction. That's why you *never* see subtraction mentioned in floating point operation counts. This will be the last time I comment.

Comment: BUT is 'subtraction' wrong in this case? "you only need half as many complex multiplcations" Why do you only need half as many complex multiplications? Because of the 'N/2' in front?

Comment: You're getting hung up on small details (addition and subtraction are the same thing) while failing to grasp the bigger picture (FFT-based convolution is inefficient for small kernels).

Comment: I suggest we stop feeding the troll

Comment: @Hilmar I'm not a troll, just a person trying to understand the theory.